# Change colour of clicked on element after confirming sweet alert

Tags: jquery

When I click on a particular class, a sweet alert pops up. If I confirm, it should change the background colour of the element I clicked on and change the background colour of the existing element. If I was doing this straight away after the click I could have just used "this" like:

```
$(this).css("background-color", "red");
```

But since I want to do it after the sweet alert, I can't use this and don't know how to get the clicked class.

```
$( ".thumbs" ).on("click", ".thumb-wrapper", function() {
        var prodId = $( ".featured-wrapper" ).data("prodid");
        var prodName = $(this).data("name");


        swal({
                title: 'Set Featured image',
                text: "Are you sure you want to change it?",
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes, change it!'
            }).then(function () {
                swal(
                    'Changed!',
                    'Featured image changed.',
                    'success'
                )


                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'functions/changed-featured-img.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            prodId: prodId,
                            prodName: prodName
                        },
                    })
                    .done(function (data) {
                        $( ".featured-wrapper" ).css("background-color", "white");
                   // need to change the clicked class background to red. 

                    })
                    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
                        console.warn(jqXHR.responseText);
                });
        })
            .catch(swal.noop)
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your clicked element to a variable (before calling `swal()`):

```
var $this = $(this);
```

In your later function use:

```
$this.css("background-color", "red");
```

Answer (score 1):

add variable tis = $(this);

```
$( ".thumbs" ).on("click", ".thumb-wrapper", function() {
 tis = $(this);
```

and finally use

```
tis.css("background-color", "white");
```

in your ajax success function

Answer (score 0):

Use body instead of '.thumb'

$( "document.body" ).on("click", ".thumb-wrapper", function() { }

Comment: I am not expert, but isn't it better to use the closest div instead of the whole body?

Comment: yes you are right. For best performance u can use document.body